Galois group of a simple algebraic extension acts transitively on the roots, and generalization.
In class, we were introduced the following theorem:

Let $E/F$ be a simple algebraic field extension, meaning $E=F(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha \in E$ algebraic over $F$. Then for any $\beta \in E$ a root of $m_\alpha$, the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$, there exists a unique $\sigma \in G:= \textrm{Gal}(E/F)$ such that $\sigma (\alpha)=\beta$. In addition, there exists a bijection between $G$ and the set of roots of $m_\alpha$.

My questions are:

Shouldn't the end of the theorem say that "there exists a bijection between $G$ and the set of roots of $m_\alpha$ in $\textbf{E}$"? Since $E$ isn't necessarily the splitting field of $m_\alpha$. Or for some reason $E$ being a simple extension obtained by adding $\alpha$ must be the splitting field of $m_\alpha$?
Does this imply that $G$ acts transitively on the set of roots of $m_\alpha$? I think so (you can compose elements of $G$ to get another element of $G$ that maps a root to a root), but again I'm not sure if it acts transitively on the set of all roots, or just the roots in $E$.
In the case that $E/F$ isn't a simple extension, but it is algebraic and finitely generated (say $E=F(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)$ for $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ algebraic over $F$)
then there's a tower of field extensions $F=F_0\subseteq F_1=F(\alpha_1) \subseteq ... \subseteq F(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)=E$ such that $F_i/F_{i-1}$ is a simple extension for all $i=1,2,...,n$. By using the theorem above repeatedly for each simple extension, can we find the Galois group of $E/F$? What would be the polynomial "of interest" to check how $G$ acts on its roots? I thought maybe $ m(x)= \prod_{i=1}^{n} m_i(x) $ where $m_i$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha_i$ over $F_{i-1}$, but since each extension isn't necessarily of degree $>1$, we might get repeated factors.

This is all in part of trying to understand how to analyze the Galois group of a field extension and its action in the general case, and here I'm trying to understand if the case in which the extension is simple and algebraic can be generalized to the case that the extension is finitely generated and algebraic.
Thank you!
Edit
I think that it really should say the set of roots of $m_\alpha$ in $E$. For example, $E=\mathbb Q(\root 3 \of 2)$ is a simple algebraic extension of $\mathbb Q$, and the minimal polynomial of $\root 3 \of 2$ over $\mathbb Q$ is $f(x)=x^3-2$, and the roots of $f$ are $\root 3 \of 2, \root 3 \of 2 \zeta_3, \root 3 \of 2 \zeta_3^2$, and only $\root 3 \of 2$ is in $E$, hence the Galois group of $E/F$ is $\{1\}$.

It indeed should be the roots in $E$. That being said, most books use the notation $\text{Gal}(E/F)$ only when $E/F$ is a Galois extension, in which case $m_{\alpha}$ must split in $E$. For general field extensions, the automorphism group is usually denoted by $\text{Aut}(E/F)$.

I agree with @Mark. I think it's misleading to speak of the Galois Group when the extension isn't Galois.
